# She went to Peshawar vs she had gone to Peshawar

Tags: phrase-meaning

If I ask a friend that where was she yesterday? The proper answer is fisrt one. But Is the second answer make any sense?

Comment: You've edited your question which unfortunately invalidates @JavaLatte's informative answer. Both would be understood to explain what your friend did yesterday, however the second would be used with other information e.g. "she had gone to Peshawar to see a friend", on it's own, the first is more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not passive voice. You can only make a passive voice sentence with a transitive verb- a verb that takes a direct object. For example, here is an active voice and a passive voice sentence using the transitive verb **give**.

> A gives B to C
>
> B is given to C

**go** is an intransitive verb- there is no B, so you can't make a passive voice sentence from it.

> A went to C.

You will find more information about passive voice [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/active-and-passive-voice).